# What is the Vim Latex-Suite shortcut for inline math parenthesis?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

Vim Latex-Suite has shortcuts for typing `\left(` and `\right)` just by typing `((`.  What is the shortcut for typing `\(` and `\)`?

Comment: I too was wondering this. For the old inline math style, typing `$$` will put the cursor back between the dollar signs (in insert mode). That style of inline is clearly less desirable however...

Answer (score 3):

There is not one, but you can create it.

You can put these lines in your `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim`. (I put mine in `~/.vim/bundle/vim-latex/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim` instead, because I used `neobundle` to install the plugin).

```
:call IMAP('FD', '\[ <++> \]<++>', 'tex') 
:call IMAP('DF', '\( <++> \)<++>', 'tex')
```

So now each time I type in Insert Mode `FD` I get a display mode and `DF` an inline mode. Then I enter my expression and I type the typical shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to continue typing my text.

For more info you can take a look in the [documentation](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/ls-new-macros.html).